# JavaScript to C# conversion - unknown data type

Tags: c#, javascript, var

Hi I am converting JavaScript to C# code, however I cannot figure out how would I write the following into C#? Any help?

```
var MyValues = { 
"Values1": [ 
    0.0, 2.33, -3,
    0.0, 1.0,      0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,      1.0
],
"Values2": [ 
    1.0,      2.0, 0.0,
    1.567207, 0.0, 2.224827,
    0.2,      0.0, 1.0
],
"Values3": [
    0.0,       0.0,      0.0,
    0.0,       1.0,      0.0,
    -3.222, 1.2209, 0.0
]
```

};

Comment: Is it Java (or) Javascript? I don't think there is var type in Java.

Comment: do you mean javascript? that does not looklike Java to me

Comment: That's not Java, for sure. It may be Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this. This is an explicit way of doing it.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<String, double[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, double[]>();
        dict.Add("Values1", new double[] { 0.0, 2.33, -3, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 });
        dict.Add("Values2", new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.567207, 0.0, 2.224827, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0 });
        dict.Add("Values3", new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -3.222, 1.2209, 0.0 });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This compiles

```
var MyValues = new
{
    Values1 = new[]{
        0.0, 2.33, -3,
        0.0, 1.0,      0.0,
        0.0, 0.0,      1.0
    },
    Values2 = new[]{ 
        1.0,      2.0, 0.0,
        1.567207, 0.0, 2.224827,
        0.2,      0.0, 1.0
    },
    Values3 = new[]{
        0.0,       0.0,      0.0,
        0.0,       1.0,      0.0,
        -3.222, 1.2209, 0.0
    }
};
```